# Marketing Cloud Push SDK iOS Keychain crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, ios

We are trying to implement Mobile SDK on iOS and Android. We haven't encountered any issues on Android, but on iOS the app keeps crashing.

We have a Dev App and we deploy our builds using TestFlight (App Store option) with 'Manage Version' unticked (we know the init can fail if the checkbox is ticked). After that, if the app is left open in the background overnight, it starts crashing with the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: com.salesforce.security.keychainException 
dictionaryItemFromKeychain: Error attempting to look up keychain item: errSecInteractionNotAllowed
```

We've done a clean install this morning and this is the log we managed to get:

```
default 09:46:03.873790+0200 Freshful MKT msg: SDK initializing with version: 1.0.3
default 09:46:03.873872+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Starting Module initialization: MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule with version compatibility: 8.0.2 - 8.9.9
default 09:46:03.874893+0200 Freshful MKT msg: New operation (1 of 100) added to the `sfmcsdk.module.push.tasks` queue.
default 09:46:03.875633+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App id keychain data missing or corrupted. Attempting to reset.
default 09:46:03.875665+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Saving the new base app identifier to the keychain.
default 09:46:03.882098+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Successfully created a new base app identifier and stored it in the keychain.
default 09:46:03.918031+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Creating secure key using secure enclave
default 09:46:03.939745+0200 Freshful MKT msg: There is no value associated with key: "registrationId"
default 09:46:03.941867+0200 Freshful MKT msg: StorageManager was initialized with new registration id (B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8).
default 09:46:03.942337+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Behavior listening started.
default 09:46:03.978509+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: MainNavigationController.
default 09:46:03.980045+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: SplashViewController.
default 09:46:03.980092+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<SplashView>.
default 09:46:03.987786+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App is active.
default 09:46:03.992415+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Storing current version "1.6" in keychain (first time use).
default 09:46:04.094260+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Module `push` subscribed to receive events.
default 09:46:04.094290+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate set` file: `MarketingCloudSDK+URLHandling.m` line: `line: 30`
default 09:46:04.094322+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Module `MarketingCloudSDK.PushModule` initialized.
default 09:46:04.095829+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `network request SFMCNetworkRequest` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 231`
default 09:46:04.519089+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `network request complete with status 202 taskError (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 239`
default 09:46:04.521625+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `control channel response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283ea1700> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45/sync/B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8 } { Status Code: 202, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
253
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:04 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (<…>
default 09:46:04.521658+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `network request succeeded with status: 202` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 277`
default 09:46:04.521689+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `status code 202, processing only blocked node from sync route response` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 300`
default 09:46:04.521717+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `Control channel blocked = 0, (0), privacyMode = 0, (0)` file: `MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m` line: `line: 1011`
default 09:46:04.521810+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `blocking MarketingCloudSDKMigration via control channel payload
{
nodes = (
{
items = {
blocked = 0;
};
name = blocked;
version = 1;
}
);
}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKMigration.m` line: `line: 547`
default 09:46:05.125991+0200 Freshful MKT msg: == WARNING == Location Services disabled by configuration method. Please enable it before trying to use Location Services.
default 09:46:05.128957+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_tags getter returning (
ALL,
iPhone,
IOS
)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 283`
default 09:46:05.129283+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_attributes getter returning (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 437`
default 09:46:05.129393+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_attributes getter returning (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 437`
default 09:46:05.129481+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_tags getter returning (
ALL,
iPhone,
IOS
)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 283`
default 09:46:05.130270+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `$appOpen` received on the event bus.
default 09:46:05.132180+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `$appOpen` send to `push`
default 09:46:05.132220+0200 Freshful MKT msg: New operation (0 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
default 09:46:05.132685+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Dropping self-produced event with id `7510F6B7-B711-4B4A-B8EA-FC9B2D4122AB` and name `$appOpen`.
default 09:46:05.141855+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `No triggers for key $appOpen in event <AppOpenEvent: 0x283c98cd0>` file: `MarketingCloudSDKEvent.m` line: `line: 923`
default 09:46:05.896322+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: IntroViewController.
default 09:46:05.897571+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<IntroView>.
default 09:46:08.075047+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App is active.
default 09:46:08.079731+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 644`
default 09:46:08.079778+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 0` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1086`
default 09:46:11.321063+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: TabBarViewController.
default 09:46:11.322170+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: NavigationController.
default 09:46:11.322609+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: CarouselsViewController.
default 09:46:11.322983+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<CarouselsView>.
default 09:46:18.132904+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: NavigationController.
default 09:46:18.133074+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: MoreViewController.
default 09:46:18.133822+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<MoreView>.
default 09:46:19.891465+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: TrackingPopupViewController.
default 09:46:19.892776+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<FullscreenPopupView>.
default 09:46:21.972996+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App is active.
default 09:46:21.978657+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 0` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1086`
default 09:46:23.176316+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App moved to background.
default 09:46:23.176403+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `A registration update was attempted but was blocked due to delayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet being set to `true` and the contact key not being set.` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 723`
default 09:46:23.535166+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `[{"etAppId":"b5f394fe-832b-4004-b606-3662e193fb45","deviceId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","eventDate":"2022-03-08T07:46:23.109Z","value":19,"analyticTypes":[4]}]` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 714`
default 09:46:23.535473+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283a8b460> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/event/analytic } { Status Code: 201, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
172
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:23 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" = (
DENY
);
"x-mashery-m<…>
default 09:46:23.535527+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `Success: http response code: 201` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 730`
default 09:46:23.617676+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `{"message":"Subscriber Token is required.","errorcode":10005,"documentation":""}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 2437`
default 09:46:23.617896+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x28397aec0> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/devicestatistics/v1/analytic } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
80
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:23 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" = (
DENY
);
"x-masher<…>
default 09:46:23.627249+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Failure: http response code: 400
default 09:46:23.709501+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App moved to foreground.
default 09:46:23.709666+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `preparing to get control channel data` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 212`
default 09:46:23.709866+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `network request SFMCNetworkRequest` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 231`
default 09:46:24.133085+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `network request complete with status 202 taskError (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m` line: `line: 239`
default 09:46:24.218172+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App is active.
default 09:46:24.769996+0200 Freshful MKT msg: == WARNING == Location Services disabled by configuration method. Please enable it before trying to use Location Services.
default 09:46:24.771857+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_tags getter returning (
ALL,
iPhone,
IOS
)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 283`
default 09:46:24.771934+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_attributes getter returning (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 437`
default 09:46:24.771956+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_attributes getter returning (null)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 437`
default 09:46:24.772022+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_tags getter returning (
ALL,
iPhone,
IOS
)` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 283`
default 09:46:24.772130+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `$appOpen` received on the event bus.
default 09:46:24.772810+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `$appOpen` send to `push`
default 09:46:24.772885+0200 Freshful MKT msg: New operation (0 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
default 09:46:24.772912+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Dropping self-produced event with id `392491E1-F85F-4760-9A12-ED79CDC845E5` and name `$appOpen`.
default 09:46:24.776408+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `No triggers for key $appOpen in event <AppOpenEvent: 0x283ccc4d0>` file: `MarketingCloudSDKEvent.m` line: `line: 923`
default 09:46:28.965405+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Setting `customer273` as profileId for all subscribed modules triggered.
default 09:46:28.965440+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.
default 09:46:28.965466+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `IdentityEvent` send to `push`
default 09:46:28.965487+0200 Freshful MKT msg: New operation (0 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
default 09:46:28.965512+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_setContactKey customer273 succeeded` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m` line: `line: 40`
default 09:46:28.965537+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 644`
default 09:46:28.965562+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `IdentityEvent` received on the event bus.
default 09:46:28.965585+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Message `IdentityEvent` send to `push`
default 09:46:28.965610+0200 Freshful MKT msg: New operation (1 of 100) added to the sfmcsdk.eventbus.push queue.
default 09:46:28.965682+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Dropping self-produced event with id `2A0C25E0-D811-4D87-83A0-C1C2D456FE9A` and name `IdentityEvent`.
default 09:46:31.030865+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: NotificationsSettingsViewController.
default 09:46:31.032708+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App screen changed. Screen entry: UIHostingController<NotificationsSettingsView>.
default 09:46:33.543071+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_setDeviceToken = {length = 32, bytes = 0xbb51c0d5 9f5de207 461aec48 4fc21acf ... 5281bcb0 dff3d749 }` file: `MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m` line: `line: 779`
default 09:46:33.543705+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 644`
default 09:46:33.543737+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `device token has been set in the SDK with value: bb51c0d59f5de207461aec484fc21acfd48912a6701ceee55281bcb0dff3d749` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1164`
default 09:46:33.757884+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App is active.
default 09:46:33.763020+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 644`
default 09:46:33.763346+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1086`
default 09:46:33.763406+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration key path observer for blob` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 644`
default 09:46:34.123959+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `sfmc_setDeviceToken = {length = 32, bytes = 0xbb51c0d5 9f5de207 461aec48 4fc21acf ... 5281bcb0 dff3d749 }` file: `MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m` line: `line: 779`
default 09:46:34.124012+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `device token has been set in the SDK with value: bb51c0d59f5de207461aec484fc21acfd48912a6701ceee55281bcb0dff3d749` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1164`
default 09:46:34.652997+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1086`
default 09:46:35.294135+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 1086`
default 09:46:38.703741+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `{"nodes":[{"version":1,"name":"event","items":[{"event":{"eventDateUtc":"2022-03-08T07:46:24.773Z","applicationId":"B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45","deviceId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","metadata":{"dST":false,"sdk_Version":"8.0.3","identity":{"moduleIdentities":{"push":{"applicationId":"B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45","customProperties":{"tags":["iPhone","ALL","IOS"],"deviceId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8"},"installationId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8"}},"registrationId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","platformType":"iOS"},"location_Enabled":false,"etAppId":"B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45","platform_Version":"15.2.1","backgroundRefreshEnabled":"notDetermined","locale":"ro_RO","platform":"iOS","timeZone":"7200","hwid":"iPhone","push_Enabled":true,"deviceID":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","app_Version":"1.6"},"name":"$appOpen"},"eventType":105},{"event":{"eventDateUtc":"2022-03-08T07:46:24.006Z","applicationId":"B5F394FE-832B-4004<…>
default 09:46:38.917602+0200 Freshful MKT msg: App moved to background.
default 09:46:38.918396+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration json payload is {
"app_Version" = "1.6";
dST = 0;
deviceID = "B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8";
"device_Token" = bb51c0d59f5de207461aec484fc21acfd48912a6701ceee55281bcb0dff3d749;
etAppId = "B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45";
hwid = "iPhone14,3";
locale = "ro_RO";
"location_Enabled" = 0;
platform = iOS;
"platform_Version" = "15.2.1";
"proximity_Enabled" = 0;
"push_Enabled" = true;
quietPushEnabled = 0;
"sdk_Version" = "8.0.3";
subscriberKey = customer273;
tags = (
ALL,
IOS,
iPhone
);
timeZone = 7200;
}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 758`
default 09:46:39.064726+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `[{"value":15,"analyticTypes":[4],"etAppId":"B5F394FE-832B-4004-B606-3662E193FB45","deviceid":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","eventDate":"2022-03-08T07:46:38.910Z"}]` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 693`
default 09:46:39.077099+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `{"message":"Subscriber Token is required.","errorcode":10005,"documentation":""}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 2437`
default 09:46:39.077184+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2839a9660> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/devicestatistics/v1/analytic } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
80
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:38 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" = (
DENY
);
"x-masher<…>
default 09:46:39.083107+0200 Freshful MKT msg: Failure: http response code: 400
default 09:46:39.193944+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `[{"etAppId":"b5f394fe-832b-4004-b606-3662e193fb45","deviceId":"B98E8E73-0F78-478C-8013-150896206FC8","eventDate":"2022-03-08T07:46:38.91Z","value":15,"analyticTypes":[4]}]` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 714`
default 09:46:39.194219+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283ab9320> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/event/analytic } { Status Code: 201, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
171
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:39 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"x-content-type-options" = (
nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" = (
DENY
);
"x-mashery-m<…>
default 09:46:39.194271+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `Success: http response code: 201` file: `MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m` line: `line: 730`
default 09:46:39.270445+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2839b5280> { URL: https://mcw5wdmxbjmzp7smq252cl02rjgy.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/registration } { Status Code: 201, Headers {
"Cache-Control" = (
"no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
);
Connection = (
"keep-alive"
);
"Content-Length" = (
511
);
"Content-Security-Policy" = (
"upgrade-insecure-requests"
);
"Content-Type" = (
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date = (
"Tue, 08 Mar 2022 07:46:39 GMT"
);
"Keep-Alive" = (
"timeout=5"
);
"Referrer-Policy" = (
"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" = (
"max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
);
Vary = (
"Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
);
"X-Subscriber-Token" = (
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cGUiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3Nh<…>
default 09:46:39.270473+0200 Freshful MKT msg: log: `registration response generated payloadHash: {length = 20, bytes = 0x5ef26c19b3ba03df6d846d69807513add5c86d6c}` file: `MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m` line: `line: 809`
```

We don't have a log from the error because the release is made using TestFlight in production, but this is what we get from Firebase and Apple reports:

```
Fatal Exception: com.salesforce.security.keychainException
0 CoreFoundation 0x990fc __exceptionPreprocess
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x15d64 objc_exception_throw
2 SFMCSDK 0xf26c _hidden#510_ + 164 (__hidden#552_:164)
3 SFMCSDK 0xf960 _hidden#514_ + 250 (__hidden#552_:250)
4 SFMCSDK 0xf050 _hidden#505_ + 132 (__hidden#552_:132)
5 SFMCSDK 0xee84 _hidden#503_ + 107 (__hidden#552_:107)
6 SFMCSDK 0x6bb0 _hidden#136_ + 210 (__hidden#214_:210)
7 SFMCSDK 0xbd10 _hidden#336_ + 143 (__hidden#360_:143)
8 SFMCSDK 0xcd20 _hidden#398_ + 82 (__hidden#412_:82)
9 SFMCSDK 0x559c _hidden#16_ + 131 (__hidden#72_:131)
10 SFMCSDK 0x4f98 _hidden#9_ + 60 (__hidden#72_:60)
11 SFMCSDK 0x4f34 _hidden#6_ + 48 (__hidden#72_:48)
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x4670 _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x5f18 _dispatch_once_callout
14 SFMCSDK 0x4f14 _hidden#5_ + 84 (__hidden#77_:84)
15 SFMCSDK 0x37694 _hidden#3745_ + 19 (__hidden#2132_:19)
16 SFMCSDK 0x41068 _hidden#4363_ (__hidden#4384_)
17 SFMCSDK 0x4128c _hidden#4364_ (__hidden#657_)
18 SFMCSDK 0x1f258 _hidden#1798_ (__hidden#657_)
19 Foundation 0x4fcac __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__
20 Foundation 0x5dd50 __NSOQSchedule_f
21 libdispatch.dylib 0x13454 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2
22 libdispatch.dylib 0x4670 _dispatch_client_callout
23 libdispatch.dylib 0x7b44 _dispatch_continuation_pop
24 libdispatch.dylib 0x71a0 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
25 libdispatch.dylib 0x15de0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
26 libdispatch.dylib 0x16608 _dispatch_worker_thread2
27 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x10b8 _pthread_wqthread
28 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0xe94 start_wqthread
```

And yes, we have contacted support and the logs are being examined by the product team. The device used is on iOS 15 with access code and face id.

Does anyone know what's the issue here?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you.  Kindly open a support case through your account representative and have them at-mention me.

Comment: Hello Bill. Like I said, we already have an open case, but I will give the account rep the case id and your name. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, they reached out today.  The support case and the internal investigation are in the correct hands.

Answer (score 2):

In case people still run into this issue. You can instruct the Marketing Cloud SDK to not treat keychain errors as fatal. Add this line of code before you initialize the SDK:

```swift
SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessErrorsAreFatal(errorsAreFatal: false)
```

Documentation:

- https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/trouble-Keychain-crash.html
- https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/trouble-ios-data-protection.html
- https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html